# Convert 2 python lists into 1 Numpy Array with the format ((list1, list2))

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

poslist = []
numlist = []
i = 1

num = int(input('Number to check?'))
plt.title(str(num) + ': Collatz Graph')
plt.xlabel('Step')
plt.ylabel('Value')
print(num)
poslist.append(i)
numlist.append(num)

while True:
    i = i + 1
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num // 2
        print(num)
    elif num == 1:
        break
    else:
        num = num * 3
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        poslist.append(i)
        numlist.append(num)

axislist = np.array((poslist, numlist))
print(axislist)
plt.plot(axislist)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to turn 2 lists into one Numpy Array. `poslist`, the first list, will add a number with each step that increments by 1 from the previous. (e.g `[1, 2, 3, 4]`). The second list, `numlist`, will append a number each step that corresponds with the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). I need to combine these two with the format: `((poslist, numlist))`. This will then be input into the `matplotlib.plot()` function which will convert it to a graph.
`poslist` will show the x-axis on the line graph, and `numlist` will show the y-axis. However, with the code I have, it does not output a continuous line of the value changing, but it outputs many coloured lines with no discernable origin, except that one starts at 0 and ends at the value that is run through the code on the y-axis, going from 0 to 1 on the x-axis:

[image: graph when input is 100]

Comment: Why not just `plt.plot(poslist, numlist)`?

Comment: Yeah that works, I just have to change it to `plt.plot(*(poslist, numlist))`. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `plt.plot(*(poslist, numlist))` is just the same as `plt.plot(poslist, numlist)`. Why do you want to complicate things so much?

Comment: honestly, I am very new to this so I wasn’t sure of the best solution. If there is a better way, I’ll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `plt.plot(*axislist)`.

By default, plt.plot parses a single argument as y-coordinates. Hence, in your case each column is used to define a line.
You need to pass both x coordinates and y coordinates, which you can do by adding *. In Python, * will split the numpy array into two subarrays defined by its rows.